# How I can validate multiple textareas with javascript

Tags: javascript

Requirement :
All textareas should be validated for null values and if any one contains null values textarea should get highlighted.

Issue :
I am able to validate single textarea however its not validating pending once.
Can we validate multiple textareas at the same time?

Java Script Code :

```
My updated JS code as below :
```

var score_elem_nm_arr_len=score_elem_nm_arr.length;
    for(k=0; k

```
{
    var score_elem_com_desc = new Array(k);
    //var lengt=score_elem_com_desc.length;
    var score_elem_com_desc1="score_elem_com_desc"+k.toString();
    var score_elem_com_desc = trim(document.getElementById(score_elem_com_desc1.toString()).value);
    if (score_elem_com_desc.length < 1) 
    {
            window.alert("Test additional comment(mon_edit)");
            document.forms[0].score_elem_com_desc.focus();
            document.getElementById('div_prg_upd').innerHTML='';
            return;
    }
}
```

JSP code:

```
<html:textarea id="score_elem_com_desc" name="score_elem_com_descp" 
    property="score_elem_com_desc" 
    styleId="score_elem_com_desc" value="<%= val %>" 
    styleClass=" detail texta" onkeyup="return setMaxLength(this, 2000)">    
</html:textarea> 
Submit Button : 
<input type="button" name="but_upd" value="Submit" class="pushbut1" 
    onClick="document.getElementById('div_prg_upd').innerHTML='Submitting data...please wait...';document.forms[0].but.value='U';mon_edit2_validatefields();">
```

Technologies used are : HTML, Struts 1, Java Script.

Comment: Do not add JSP code. Add relevant resulting HTML markup to your question.

Comment: Where by "null values" you mean "empty strings"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
//get all textarea
k =document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
//do validation on each textarea
for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    //do validation on k[i].value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use score_elem_com_desc as class in text area.

```
var allTextArea = document.getElementsByClassName('score_elem_com_desc');
for(var k = 0; k < allTextArea.length; k++){
   if(!allTextArea[k].value) {
      allTextArea[k].focus();
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I create any misunderstanding here issue is I am able to validate for single textarea. However there are 13 textareas which I am trying to validate with constant logic by using for loop. I have updated my js code.

Comment: add above mention class in all your textareas and above code will code work. it will focus on the text area which have no value.

Comment: It is giving error when I am trying to add class="score_elem_com_desc" in html:textarea as not found atribute for jsp.

Comment: ok. update this and check: var allTextArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

Comment: Still facing issue, when I am trying to use above code. I am receiving arraylist consisting 16 textareas with values. I am not able to retrive and validate the same.

Comment: also if your are not wrapping the above code in function, replace return with break statement as return work for functions.